# Float right moves the next line down up

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have this below and when I put a float right on it, the next line below comes up to the same line as the first line that has the date. How can I keep them on two different lines?

```
<div class="col-sm-10">
    <div class="row" style="float: right;">Nov 02 2018</div>
    <div class="row">George</div>
    <div class="row">Hi George, how are you?</div>
</div>
```

Comment: so what exactly are you trying to achieve? First line `date` is in `right-side` then the second line `George` is in below of the `date`?

Comment: no, George sites on the same line as the date

Comment: then your code is working

Comment: no, I don't want the date and George on the same line, I want them on two different lines

Comment: then just use `<br>` after `date`

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap has classes like `float-right` try it.

[Bootstrap Float Classes](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/utilities/float/)

Answer (score 0):

Set the `clear:both` rule on the second element:

```css
.first{
   float:right;
}

.second{
   clear:both;
}
```

```html
<div class="col-sm-10">
    <div class="row first">Nov 02 2018</div>
    <div class="row second">George</div>
    <div class="row">Hi George, how are you?</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really sure what exactly are you trying to achieve but I hope this one is correct. I added `offset-sm-1` to the `div` to put in the center and also add `<br>` at the end of the `date` to put `George` as a different line

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div class="col-sm-10 offset-sm-1">
  <div class="row" style="float: right;">Nov 02 2018</div><br>
  <div class="row">George</div>
  <div class="row">Hi George, how are you?</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

add`.clearfix` class to `.row` after float